# Looking for a way to smooth mouse movement in C#

Tags: c#, events, methods, pixel, mousemove

So, i have every single line of code ready to move and click LMB in c#, but my issue is that the coursor just teleports to desired location and it looks yerk af. Instead of "**teleporation**" happening i would like the mouse to **move smoothly** to desired position over a set amount of time (desirebly miliseconds).

I'm looking for a method similar to this:

```
public void MoveMouse(int xDelta, int yDelta, double timeInMiliseconds)...
```

Currently im using this as my moving method

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

---
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;

public static void MoveMouse(int x_Delta, int y_Delta)
{
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, xDelta, yDelta, 0, 0);
}
```

Just to clarify, im moving the mouse by a certain amount of pixels on X and Y axis, not hard-setting the position on the screen.

I already tried dividing the movement into smaller pieces, but since pixels can't be doubles it means that sometimes, when there is a remainder from the division im loosing on precision.

Any ideas how to implement that? I've read something about vectors, but i did't manage to get them working as intended :(

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate calculating correct position each time instead of using an increment:

```
int steps = 10;
for (i = 0; i <= steps; ++i)
{
    int x = i * xDelta / steps;
    int y = i * yDelta / steps;
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y, 0, 0);
}
```

This should keep a precision.

Comment: If it's still too fast, put it in an `async` method and put a `await Task.Delay(smallNumberOfMilliseconds);` in the loop

Comment: The thing is that when im dividing lets say 33 as an xDelta value by 10 steps i get 3,3, which is getting rounded to 3, so im losing 0,3 pixel of movement. And it happens every single movement. It's very important in my case becase this mistake adds-up.

Comment: @zjebinsky No. On the first step you get 3.3 rounded to `3`, on the second - 6.6 rounded to `6`, on the third - 9.9 rounded to `9`, but on the forth - 13.2 rounded to `13` (not 12). So there is no accumulation of error.